# Cannot use curl with PHP on ubuntu 11.1

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use curl on my ubuntu 11.1 server.

In my script, I have the following:

```
$ch = curl_init();
```

But when I run the script, I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()
```

I thought that Curl was not installed, but when I do the following:

```
 sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libcurl4-openssl-dev' instead of 'libcurl3-dev'
curl is already the newest version.
libcurl3 is already the newest version.
```

(I did not do the update). Any ideas?

Comment: enable the extension.. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12787844/1943011

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939820/how-to-enable-curl-installed-ubuntu-lamp-stack

Comment: Perhaps it's not enabled. Try `sudo php5enmod curl` then restart your web server (if using a web server). See http://serverfault.com/questions/132551/install-php-extensions-on-ubuntu

Comment: php5enmod gives me command not found

Comment: Rahul K: your answer is for wampp, my question states that I'm on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

visit the following url.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/9293/how-do-i-install-curl-in-php5

also check the extenions by phpinfo()

Comment: In my question, I already mentioned that the installer told me that I have curl installed and it's the latest version